# Posting form in Javascript from JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

Question level : Intermediate / Beginner

I created a form with

```
`method="post" action="eh.do" onsubmit="return Form1_Validator(this)"`
```

The validation is successful and works fine when I hit submit.

But on the servlet, I have a concatenate function to merge the values together.

When the Javascript is turned on, ie when I write `onsubmit="return Form1_Validator(this)"` it shows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.lang.String.concat(Unknown Source)
    EditHelper.doPost(EditHelper.java:27)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

But once the Javascript is disabled ie I delete out `onsubmit="return Form1_Validator(this)"`, it works fine.

If all conditions are true, my script returns

```
return (true);
```

Is this the problem?

I tried `return(theForm);` but the problem remains the same!

Comment: Please post the code for the Form1_Validator function as well as code close to line 27 in EditHelper.java

Comment: I'm not sure here, but you could be processing that return block as a Java code rather than Javascript. Post your code as suggest by @svinto.
Secondly, you shouldn't be running Javascript within your server code.

Comment: I figured it out. I deleted all concatenation values and used the conventional + to concatenate, now everything works fine!

BTW.. form validation had no problem, i put out a out.print function in the servlet and the log had the passed parametres, the values where being passed.. 

@Helen I am running javascript on the client side not on the server side!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) to see how the form submit request parameters change if you add your onsubmit handler. I guess your javascript code is somehow influencing those parameters and once you see what happens, it might become obvious why this is.